# Python read CSV file with quotes and remove them for further use

Tags: python

I am reading in a CSV file using python like this...

```
CSV File
"sku","title","category","description"
73,"clothes","trouser","This is a pair of trousers, it has pockets"


with open(filename) as csv_file:

    reader= csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')

    for sku, title, category, description in reader:

        print(sku)
        print(title)
        print(category)
        print(description)
```

This gives me the following,,

```
73
"clothes"
"trouser"
"This is a pair of trousers, it has pockets"
```

I want to take these values and use them for something else, but the quotes are now a problem, I obviously need them in the initial read to make sure that the commas are not seen as a new item.

But what is the best way to strip them now so I can use them elsewhere?

Comment: Why the delimiter is `\t` and not `,`?

Comment: Sorry, typo. Have corrected now

Comment: Your supposed extract of CSV file also contains a typo. Please provide a  [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `quoting` parameter with `csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL`. Prefer use, `DictReader` because your file has headers:

```
with open('data.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for d in reader:
        print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'sku': '73', 'title': 'clothes', 'category': 'trouser',
 'description': 'This is a pair of trousers, it has pockets'}
```

You can also use `csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC` to get numeric values (see 'sku' entry):

```
with open('data.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
    for d in reader:
        print(d)

# Output
{'sku': 73.0, 'title': 'clothes', 'category': 'trouser',
 'description': 'This is a pair of trousers, it has pockets'}
```